# WebAPI routes in IIS Logs

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have a large Web API project that runs my company's e-commerce site. I just noticed that any request to the web API shows the URI-stem as root in the IIS logs. Is there a way to see the full route to the API end point that was called?

I am trying to use File Beats in our Elastic Search/Log Stash/Kibana (ELK) setup. We got the File Beat setup to monitor the IIS log today and just showing the root does not give us the information that we are looking for in our logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the Host(cs-host) field in the IIS managament console logging window. You can also try to add the HTTP_URL custom server variable:

[image: IIS Management Console Logging Configuration]

Comment: That worked. I added the cs-host field. It appended the full route to the cs-uri-stem and then the query string was put in the correct field as well. We just got that all the way up into Kibana without issue.